# Printing out the NOTICE from Truncate Cascade?

Tags: php, postgresql, psql, truncate, cascade

I want to retrieve the "NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table...." statements that get spat out in terminal when running a truncate cascade in postgres, from php.

For example if i run a "TRUNCATE table_name CASCADE;" inside a BEGIN, ROLLBACK statement, is there any way I can fetch those notices of what is going to be truncated? As they are in order of deletion - This would be a big help.

Thanks

Comment: maybe [this could help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-notice.php). Did you take a look at it ?

Comment: @gogaz Didn't even think of this! Life saver! THANK YOU.

Comment: gogaz' solution is the way to go. You could capture the warnings using output buffering, but if your PHP server is configured properly those warnings won't show up (information disclosure).

Comment: Realized my local machine has PHP 7.1.7 but the server im working on is PHP 5.X and we have no way of upgrading. 

The "option" parameter for pg_last_notice was only added in for 7.1.0 PHP version so i cant specify to return ALL notices... Is there anyway using the standard pg_last_notice i can return all notices from the last query/ transaction? Failing that i'm going to have to store the order in a table.... any help appreciated